# Custom GPU Lightmapper in Unity3D - want to implement Directional light maps?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Hi, i am working on a custom GPU lightmapper for Unity3D game engine. Currently it supports only diffuse ( normal ) light maps. What i would like to do now is to implement "Directional Lightmaps". The point is that i am not really sure what is the proper math behind it. It is something about computing the dominant light direction multiplied by some factor from the diffuse ( color ) lightmaps.

So, is there someone who is into these things and can explain a bit how to implement directional light maps. The Lightmapper is using PathTracing.

Thanks !